# Challenges with SWIFT Transfers and Name Sanctions

Tags: banking, money-transfer, swift

My SWIFT transfers, approximately 5000 USD per year, have consistently been held by the intermediary bank. For the past 6 months, all of my payments are blocked. My clients are universities and colleges in the UK and US, and one of them told me that my name "Muhammad" is sanctioned. The irony is that when I transfer money to UK or US, then it goes fine. Don’t you think it is racist and discriminating? How can I solve this issue permanently?

Comment: There are way too many Muhammads to sanction just by the first name. You'll need to speak with the intermediary bank (or find a different bank to handle the transfers for you)

Comment: I mentioned that not one but multiple transactions are halted. All transactions are coming through different intermediary banks.